# How can I took data consistently whether from room database or activity intent in android background service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I called my service class by intent with passing values there and I want to display these texts over the screen(drow over screen permission needed) even the app closed. However, it is working when app alive but when I close the app, `onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int)` method runs again with a null intent value which is the problem that I am losing my data that I was getting from intent. I tried passing these values in sharedPreference when onStartCommand runs first on app alive, then if the app closes I am not able to get data from sharedPreference. How can I get data in background service, from `room database`, `sharedPreference` or `intent` and which is best practice?

````java
class PopupService: Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

//Initializing value 
    var interval:Long = 500
    val mTimer = Timer()
    lateinit var pref: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var wm:WindowManager
    lateinit var textView:TextView
    lateinit var data:ArrayList<String>


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        Log.d("MyNameisNotName","Started")

        //I am getting arrayList and storing to data. 
        if(intent!= null)
        data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("messages")

      //Initializing values to popup texts on screen
        wm = this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val inflater: LayoutInflater = this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        textView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, null) as TextView
        val data = App.getDb
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimeDisplayTimerTask(wm,textView,data), 0, interval)

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }


//Function to handle action periodiaclly in given duration
    class TimeDisplayTimerTask(val wm: WindowManager,val textView: TextView,val db:AppDb) : TimerTask() {

        var params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
            else
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)


        val handler = Handler()

        fun textDecoration(textView: TextView,data:List<Memo>) {
            try {
                textView.text = data[Random.nextInt(data.size-1)].text
                textView.textSize = 45f
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)
            }catch (e:Exception){

            }
        }

        override fun run() {

         val myRun = Runnable{
                val displaymetrics = DisplayMetrics()

                wm.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displaymetrics)
                val width = displaymetrics.widthPixels
                val height = displaymetrics.heightPixels

                params.x = Random.nextInt(width - 10)
                params.y = Random.nextInt(height - 10)
                var data = db.getMemoDao.getAll().value

                    Log.d("MyNameisNotName","Hi there"+data?.size.toString())
                    if(data!=null)
                textDecoration(textView,data)


                if (textView.isShown)
                    wm.removeView(textView)

                wm.addView(textView, params)
            }

                handler.post(myRun)
        }

        override fun cancel(): Boolean {
            if(textView.isShown)
                wm.removeView(textView)
            return super.cancel()
        }

    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if(textView.isShown)
            wm.removeView(textView)
        try{
            mTimer.cancel()
        }catch (e:Exception){

        }
        Log.d("MyNameisNotName","Destroyed")

    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your Service is Killed probably when you run your App on Android 8.0 and higher,

You can try to run your Service in Foreground if it meet the criteria(really useful and a Notification is shown), so it should not be killed,

You can read more about starting a Service as Foreground Service Here :

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground

Or if you keep your Service implementation(not recommended), You could try to return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT in onStartCommand() this will redeliver the original Intent